# Publish on TFS does not find the pubxml file for Node.js test project

Tags: node.js, testing, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I created a Node.js project for an protractor test environment using the Node.js Tools to test a web application on a team foundation server. The test project and the web application are in one solution file. However, if i want to deploy the Node.js project on the tfs, it is not able to find the pubxml file located in the web application project.

Error log:

```
12>CoreCompile:
     Creating directory "bin".
     Copying file from "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Node.js Tools\Microsoft.NodejsTools.WebRole.dll" to "bin\Microsoft.NodejsTools.WebRole.dll".
   ValidatePublishProfileSettings:
     Validating PublishProfile(TestProfile) settings.
12>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4364,5): error : The value for PublishProfile is set to 'TestProfile', expected to find the file at '<PATH>\TestProject.Web.Protractor.Tests\__profiles\TestProfile.pubxml' but it could not be found. [<PATH>\TestProject.Web.Protractor.Tests.njsproj]
12>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4371,4): error : PublishProfile(TestProfile) is set. But the $(WebPublishMethod) does not have a valid value.  Current Value is "". [<PATH>\TestProject.Web.Protractor.Tests.njsproj]
12>Done Building Project "<PATH>\TestProject.Web.Protractor.Tests.njsproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets i found the PublishProfileRootFolder variable to change the search path for the pubxml file.

First i tried to place the variable inside the MSBuild arguments. However, this raised problems with other test projects and i was not able to use variables like the `$(SolutionDir)`.

I ended trying to use the PublishProfileRootFolder variable inside the project file and this works now:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <PublishProfileRootFolder>$(SolutionDir)PathToWebApplication\Properties\PublishProfiles</PublishProfileRootFolder>
</PropertyGroup>
...
```

PS: Additionally you need a Web.config file, placed in the project root of the test project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="on"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```